Is there anyway to know when an adb command managed by C# System.Diagnostics.Process finished?
I need to change tons of my Android picture's date and the easiest way seem to be using adb shell with touch command. I don't know why but adb shell touch ... does not work and it says "readonly file system". However, if I run adb shell and then proceed to run touch in that process, it's possible.
I already wrote something like this
var adb = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("adb", "shell")
{
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
});
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(adb);

var outputTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (!adb.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = await adb.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
});

adb.StandardInput.WriteLine("ls");
adb.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd sdcard/DCIM/Camera");
adb.StandardInput.WriteLine("touch -d \"2011-01-01 00:00:00\" receipt_660cb153bd075.jpg");
adb.StandardInput.WriteLine("stat receipt_660cb153bd075.jpg");

The problem is, how do I know when ls output finished since the C# Process instance is not technically done?

I am not sure this is the best solution but right now I append an echo <something unique to my app> to signal an end of a command and then I read the output continously until I reach that signal
// Usage:
using var reader = new ShellOutputReader(adb.StandardOutput.BaseStream);

adb.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd sdcard/DCIM/Camera");

var lsOutputTask = reader.ReadUntilCompleteAsync();
// Append the signal at the end of the command
adb.StandardInput.WriteLine($"ls;echo {ShellOutputReader.FinishToken}");
var lsOutput = await lsOutputTask;

// This should output the result of the `ls` command
Console.WriteLine(lsOutput);

// The reader
class ShellOutputReader : IDisposable
{
    public const string FinishToken = "COMMAND_FINISHED";

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new();
    readonly StringBuilder curr = new();
    readonly StreamReader reader;

    public ShellOutputReader(Stream stream)
    {
        reader = new(stream);

        var token = cts.Token;
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                if (line == FinishToken)
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(curr.ToString());
                    tcs = new();
                    curr.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    curr.AppendLine(line);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadUntilCompleteAsync()
    {
        return await tcs.Task;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}


Did you try to add adb.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit"); at the end? Now the adb process should exit

@SirRufo Ah right! I forgot about that. Thanks for the reminder.
